# Jquery animation queue does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

I want to create a staggered animation for four elements, so I first add four animations to a custom queue, and then I use dequeue. However, the outcome is that only the last element is animated. Any ideas what is going wrong? Thanks!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      div span {position:absolute;}
    </style>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div").lettering();
        var myQueue = $({});
        var nodes = $("div").children();
        for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
          var currentNode = $(nodes[i]);
          var animateOptions = {};
          animateOptions['top'] = (i+1)*20;
          animateOptions['left'] = (i+1)*20;
          animateOptions['opacity'] = 0.3;
          animateOptions['queue'] = false;
          animateOptions['duration'] = 1000;
          //currentNode.animate(animateOptions); // if a uncomment this line, all letters are animated, but simultaneously, which I don't want
          myQueue.queue('custom', function(next) {
            currentNode.animate(animateOptions);
            next();
          });
        };
        myQueue.dequeue('custom');
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here, though there are 4 different version of `animateOptions` in the queue, there is only one version of `i` for each `animateOptions`, which is the last value of `i`.
That's why it is animating for only once and for the last character.
I don't know what you mean by staggering motion, you have to introduce multiple loops to get the desired effect, or sequence the action group in a array and then dequeue it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").lettering();
   var myQueue = $({});
   var fruits = [];
   var nodes = $("div").children();
   var i=0;
   var intervalId = setInterval(function(){
      var currentNode = $(nodes[i]);
      var animateOptions = {};
      animateOptions['top'] = (i+1)*20;
      animateOptions['left'] = (i+1)*20;
      animateOptions['opacity'] = 0.3;
      animateOptions['queue'] = false;
      animateOptions['duration'] = 1000;
      currentNode.animate(animateOptions);
      if(i>=nodes.length)
         clearInterval(intervalId);
      i++;
   },500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! However it is not yet clear to me how the correct solution would look like. What I want to achieve is that first the "T" is animated, and when that is finished, the "e" etc. So there should be four animations running consecutively instead of simultaneously. How would I do that?

Comment: You have to call the method in an interval, I edited code to my post. Hope this helps

Comment: Your code does what I had intended. Interestingly it doesn't use a queue at all. It's not clear to me why using a queue doesn't work here, but you have provided a working solution, so thanks a lot!